# sqlite3 unknown database schema when using a checkpoint?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown database schema

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tick.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20,isolation_level=None)
# conn1 = sqlite3.connect('nifty_tick.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20,isolation_level=None)

c = conn.cursor()
# c1 = conn1.cursor()

c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')

def tick_entry1(inst,timestamp,ltp, bid, ask):
    if inst == 12335874:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO niftyfut (timestamp, close, bid, ask) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                  (timestamp, ltp, bid, ask))

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global c, conn
    for t in ticks:
        if t['instrument_token'] == 12335874:
            timestamp = t['timestamp']
            ltp = t['last_price']
            inst = t['instrument_token']

            try:
                tick_entry1(inst,timestamp,ltp)
            except:
                # print('problem with db')
                pass
    c.execute('PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(FULL);')
```

I have tried:

`c.execute('PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(FULL);')`

and

`c.execute('PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(FULL)')`

### Edit

I just tried:

`c.execute('PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)')`

It seems to work. Now wondering if the following should be executed at the start.:

`c.execute("PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is saying that no database has a schema named schema.

In the documentation the *schema* is italic, which indicates that it is symbolic rather than an actual value and would be replaced with an appropriate value, the value is used to distinguish between attached databases.

e.g. if you used

```
ATTACH DATABASE the_database_path AS database2 /*<<<<<<<<<< THE SCHEMA is database2 */;
```

then you could use

```
PRAGMA database2.wal_checkpoint(FULL);
```

to checkpoint the attached database.

The initial database's schema is **main** but isn't required as it's the default if no schema is supplied.

Hence why `c.execute('PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)')` worked (as would `c.execute('PRAGMA main.wal_checkpoint(FULL)')`). i.e. the are effectively the same.

If you use `c.execute("PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 0")` then you will have to manage all the checkpointing as auto-checkpointing will be turned off (note that closing all the database connections checkpoints).

You may wish to consider :-

> Disabling the automatic checkpoint mechanism. In its default
>   configuration, SQLite will checkpoint the WAL file at the conclusion
>   of any transaction when the WAL file is more than 1000 pages long.
>   However, compile-time and run-time options exist that can disable or
>   defer this automatic checkpoint. If an application disables the
>   automatic checkpoint, then there is nothing to prevent the WAL file
>   from growing excessively. [Write-Ahead Logging - **6. Avoiding Excessively Large WAL Files**](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

I'd suggest not using `PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 0` autocheckpointing does not hinder forced checkpointing, other than if a forced checkpoint happens after an auto checkpoint (and all pages are written) and nothing has been updated then it will do nothing (gracefully), otherwise more pages would be written to the database file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The issue I was facing was the readers were taking too much time(20 seconds to read 40-50 rows). With the above checkpoint it seems to have improved considerably. In your opinion would shutting off the autocheckpoint make sense?

Comment: @Sid I doubt it, rather that more frequent checkpointing would be beneficial (rather than none). I'd suggest reading **2.3 Performance Considerations** as per the link, which includes *On the other hand, read performance deteriorates as the WAL file grows in size since each reader must check the WAL file for the content and the time needed to check the WAL file is proportional to the size of the WAL file. The wal-index helps find content in the WAL file much faster, but performance still falls off with increasing WAL file size.* Also section 3 may be useful.

Comment: @Sid that is the issue isn't checkpointing (applying the changes stored (logged) in the WAL file to the database). The issue appears to be the size of the WAL file, so you want to try to keep the size smaller. I'd be tempted to try `PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 250` or even 100. Another option could be to use TRUNCATE (see 6 about this being slower) rather then FULL, you could then check the size of the WAL file and initiate a forced checkpoint according to the file size.

Comment: I just read through the link. I think this is where the problem would be:  Checkpoint starvation. In point 6. I think I will add the `PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint = 100` or 250 while trying the `c.execute('PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)')` for now . The TRUNCATE will be the next thing I try.